# Variar Script dentro da Div

Tags: html, wordpress, script

Gostaria de incorporar um quiz em script na sidebar do meu site, são 3 quiz na verdade e não queria colocar um abaixo do outro, gostaria que eles alternassem entre si automaticamente toda vez que a página for carregada, ocupando o mesmo bloco.

É um script com variação como abaixo:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/9527749.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/9527749/">O que faz você fugir da dieta?</a></noscript>`

Gostaria de um script tipo o que uso para variar as imagens que varia toda vez que a página é carregada. Ao clicar ela leva ao site destino, essa opção não seria necessária.

```
'<script>// <![CDATA[
var max = 3;
var nrImages = 3;
function makeImages() {
this[0] = "imagem1.jpg";
this[1] = "imagem2.jpg";
this[2] = "imagem3.jpg";
this.length = nrImages;
}
function makeLinks() {
this[0] = "Link pro site";
this[1] = "Link pro site";
this[2] = "Link pro site";
this.length = nrImages;

}
var vetImages = new makeImages();
var vetLinks = new makeLinks();
var x = Math.round(Math.random()*max);
var y = max / nrImages;
for(var cont = 1;cont*y<= max;cont++) {
if (x <= (cont*y)) {
document.write("<a href="+vetLinks[cont-1]+" rel=nofollow target=_blank><img src="+vetImages[cont-1]+" border='0'/></a>");
break;
}
}
// ]]></script>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar a tag de script dinamicamente e adicionar a um elemento, um `div` por exemplo:

```
<div id="scriptQuiz"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var link = "<a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/9527749/">O que faz você fugir da dieta?</a>";
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://static.polldaddy.com/p/9527749.js";
s.innerHTML = link;
document.getElementById("scriptQuiz").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("scriptQuiz").appendChild(s);
```

Claro, você pode gerar o `href` do `link` também dinamicamente, só adaptar.